# Bedeutung von "wenigstens einmal in der Woche bei uns essen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Du kannst wenigstens einmal in der Woche bei uns essen.

Kann das heißen

> (a) Du kannst einmal oder mehrmals in der Woche bei uns essen.

oder

> (b) Du kannst einmal in der Woche bei uns essen, wenn du nichts Weiteres mit uns tun willst.

oder beides?

Comment: Klingt wie Eltern, die eigentlich das Kind am Tisch haben möchten, ihm aber – »nur verbieten ist verboten!« – keine Vorschriften machen wollen ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es kann technisch gesehen beides heißen, da „wenigstens“ nicht klar von „mindestens“ abgegrenzt ist. Für mein Sprachgefühl klingt

> wenigstens X

aber sehr stark nach Folgendem:

> Ich weiß, dass ich nicht viel haben kann, aber X wäre schon schön.

Darin liegt der Unterschied zu „mindestens“, das viel mehr in die Richtung „noch mehr“ guckt und sagt

> Ich möchte X auf jeden Fall und am besten noch mehr.

Daher würde ich den Satz im zweiten Sinn verstehen.
Es kann aber da durchaus regionale Unterschiede geben.

(Für eine detailliertere Beschreibung sowie einen Erklärungsversuch, woher der Unterschied kommt, siehe [diesen Artikel](https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/wenigstens-mindestens-zumindest-zumindest-difference/) auf meinem Blog.)

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz ist in der Tat nicht eindeutig. Beides ist möglich. In aller Regel würde ich den Satz aber interpretieren als:

> Das Mindeste was du tun kannst, ist einmal in der Woche vorbeikommen und bei uns essen.

Comment: Ich stimme Dir zu, dass beides möglich ist, aber ohne Kontext würde ich weder das eine noch das andere für wahrscheinlicher halten.

Comment: Und wenn man zuerst die Überschrift gelesen hat, hat man bereits die andere Bedeutung im Kopf.

Answer (score 3):

Auch ich bin der Meinung, daß beide Bedeutungen möglich sind - wobei ich Deinen Vorschlag (b) so verstehe, wie ihn Em1 in seiner Antwort paraphrasiert hat, also "Das Mindeste was du tun kannst, ist einmal in der Woche vorbeikommen und bei uns essen.". Wie er halte ich diese Variante auch für wahrscheinlicher, denn für (a) würde ich eher "mindestens" statt "wenigstens" verwenden.

In gesprochener Kommunikation solltest Du die Unterscheidung anhand der Satzmelodie und Betonung treffen können. Für Variante (a) müßte "wenigstens" betont sein, vor allem auch stärker als "einmal". "Essen" wäre eher unbetont, und der Satz sollte wie ein Angebot klingen. Variante (b) wäre eher ein Vorwurf, den man auch so hören müßte. "Essen" wäre auf jeden Fall deutlich betont, außerdem in der Regel auch "einmal" stärker als "wenigstens".